# Interpret sales rules

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to get a list of all possible combinations of my catalog for the promotions. So if a sales_rule is applied for product 12345 and 6789 combination, then i need to retrieve this from that rule.

How can i achieve this? The thing is that i need to dump all possible product/promotion combinations to an external application.

I got the sales rules in my code but how can i interpret them?

```
$ruleCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')
    ->addWebsiteFilter(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_promo', true);
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that for the sales rule because a sales rule may not involve products or you can get a discount from a sales rule on some products only on specific conditions (like a certain shipping address, or a certain subtotal). So one user may get a discount for a product and an other one may not, for the same product.  Off topic a bit, you can get the affected product ids for catalog rules through `$rule->getMatchingProductIds`

Comment: Thing is that it returns nothing. Even though there are products connected to the rule.

Comment: read carefully...`getMatchingProductIds` works only for CATALOG price rules. not for SHOPPING CART price rules. I added it there just as an info

Comment: Ah ok too bad since it is about the shoppingCart rules in this case. Is there no other way to do it? We have an external shop that submits their cart with an API. Therefor i want to display the rules at their place. Just the basic rules without customer stuff etc. Just the plain rules for the products